# Should I use SocketIO in PhP?

Tags: php, sockets, socket.io

Web programming is a new thing for me, so I have several questions. My goal is to interact with a online currency exchange server. Standard API sends data with a delay which makes its usage inappropriate, but the web sight also provides SocketIO interface. All I need is to listen on a socket and receive information in an infinite loop. How do I do this?

Is SocketIO different from usual socket interface? My program is written in PhP while SocketIO is a JavaScript library if I get it right. So may be I can avoid using it. What would be preferable in my case (the program isn't really supposed to do anything special except receiving data). Server uses TSL/SSL protocol.

Any example/link close to my problem would be greatly welcomed.

Thanks!

Comment: You can take a look at the php [Ratched library](http://socketo.me/) which is (kind of) a port of SocketIO for PHP

Comment: Did this problem ever get solved?

Answer (score 1):

PHP and socket.io work together. The only difference between doing it with html and with PHP is the way you link the two together (the common tutorial shows a way that only works with html, but there is another way that works with both html and php).

```
var socket = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);

var io = socket.listen(server);
```

Then remove the `app.use` and `app.get` as they are no longer needed for how this is going to be done. Then add `server.listen(8000);` at the end of the server.js. For dependencies, use: `<script src="//cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.0.js"></script>`. Then, to run your server, go to it in terminal and type `node server.js`. Then just connect to it with your client. Also, for events, in the server, use:

```
io.on('connection', function (client) {
    client.on('someEvent', function(someVariables){
        //Do something with someVariables when the client emits 'someEvent'
        io.emit('anEventToClients', someData);
    });
    client.on('anotherEvent', function(someMoreVariables){
        //Do more things with someMoreVariables when the client emits 'anotherEvent'
        io.emit('anotherEventToClients', someMoreData);
    });
});
```

And in your client code:

```
socket.emit('someEvent', variables);
socket.on('anEventToClients', function(something){
    //Code when anEventToClient is emitted from the server
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try to get deeper into SocketIO. But I didn't understand one thing: why do I need server if the web sight already provides SocketIO interface? Actually my goal is to receive push notifications from this web sight.

Comment: This is just to make sure that you don't use that `app.get` method from express, as this is a bit problematic with PHP. Other than that, it functions fine (as long as you connect it correctly) just like any other JavaScript library would with PHP.

Comment: Additionally, the server allows the connection between the client(s) and the website.